# Use CMU's sphinx4 to transcribe non-digits data

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4, cmusphinx, transcription

I am recently working on using CMU's sphinx4 for transcription and eventually forced alignment, i.e. aligning audio with its transcript.

I found a project called [AutoCap](http://imj.ucsb.edu/autocap/) that basically did what I wanted to develop. So, I installed it but it did not work. I tried tweaking it but all I obtained was incorrect timestamps.

So, I thought of using sphinx4 and giving it a go myself. I successfully transcribed a wav file using Sphinx's Transcriber.jar file. 
But I could not get it working for an audio with non-digits data. The [readme](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/README.html) page states 
'*people who want to transcribe non-digits data should modify the config.xml file to use the correct grammar, language model, and linguist to do so'*.

So, can anyone provide me some help on either of these :

- AutoCap
- Using Sphinx4 to transcribe non-digits data
- Forced Alignment

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get anymore success with this project ? Will appreciate any input .

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific project dedicated to speech to text alignment. This is not a trivial task. The development goes in a separate sphinx4 branch. You can find some details here

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/?s=long+audio+alignment

If you have any question on this project you are welcome to ask on sphinx4 forum

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/forums/forum/382337

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the same issue, i.e transcribing non digit data. I have looked briefly into the sphinx 4 programmers guide documentation, and used the language models, acoustic models, and the JSGF Grammar as suggested. however the response obtained was not up to the mark. What I believe is merely tweaking the parameters or changes in the config.xml alone will not suffice. I think we would need a home grown algorithm to go along with sphinx 4  which can perform better speech recognition. From my side.. i have used the lextreeliguist, JSGFGrammar and the trigram language model. But the response was not great. perhaps because the audio input was not exactly american english. Will work on it a bit more .. and let you know my results